# I need the male end of a cable connector that mates with THIS female connector

Tags: electrical, wiring, fan, gm, connector

I have a Jeep Wrangler in which I've had a 5.3L Chevy LS engine installed, along with the GM ECU, a custom radiator and a GM radiator fan (from a 2017 Camaro I believe).

The radiator fan has this male connector:

[image]

This plugs into this female connector:

[image]

Pigtails with the female connector are readily available.  I have not found any pigtails with the corresponding male connector.  All of the matching male connectors that I have seen so far, are part of a fan control unit.  What I need is a pigtail with the male connector.

Where can I obtain a pigtail with the appropriate male connector, or what are some common part numbers I can use to find a pigtail with this connector.  I would settle for just the connector (the type where I can solder the wires onto the supplied terminals and make my own pigtail)?

Comment: I think I'd be headed down to the junkyard to pick up the connector (maybe pick up a couple, just in case...)

Comment: Not sure I follow - you have a GM radiator fan with a male connector, but obviously no matching female connector on the Jeep?  GM can supply just about any connector if you can identify it.  Otherwise, any heavy duty connector with [what appears to be] four pins should do just fine.  Trailer light/brake harness flat connector would work - and both male/female are available everywhere.

Comment: @SteveRacer I have a GM radiator fan (male connector shown) that is plugged into a GM ECU via the female connector (also shown).  I'm having problems with the radiator and want to put the stock Jeep radiator and fan back in.  I'm anticipating I'll need a short "conversion cable" with a Jeep female connector on one end and the GM male connector (which I'm having trouble finding) on the other end.

Comment: @mbmast Cut the male off the GM fan and splice it on to the stock Jeep fan.

Comment: That connector on the fan is a Jeep connector, not GM.